# Why Validation Error is not showing in forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am building a Blog App and i am stuck on a problem.

**The Problem**

> Validation Error is not raising.

**What i am trying to do**

I made a feature that if user select `past time` in `DateTimeField` in Browser Page then a Validation error will be shown. BUT the error is showing.

forms.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_added = forms.DateTimeField(initial=timezone.now)

        def clean_date(self):
            date_added = self.cleaned_data['date_added']
            if date_added.date() < datetime.date_added.today():
                raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
            return date_added
```

views.py

```
def new__blog_post(request,user_id):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        new_post = form.save()
        new_post.post_owner = request.user
        new_post.save()
        return redirect('mains:posts',user_id=user_id)

    context = {'form':form,'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'new_blog_post.html', context)
```

My other question related to this , [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265246/the-post-could-not-be-created-because-the-data-didnt-validate-when-i-set-pa)

I don't know what i am doing wrong in this.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To validate data you need to call `Form.is_valid()`. See [Using forms to validate data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data).

So call first `is_valid()`:

```
def new__blog_post(request,user_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save()
            new_post.post_owner = request.user
            new_post.save()
            return redirect('mains:posts',user_id=user_id)
    else:
         form = PostForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'form':form,'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'new_blog_post.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import datetime


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_added = forms.DateTimeField(initial=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ["date_added", ...]
    
    def clean_date_added(self):
        date_added = self.cleaned_data['date_added']
        if date_added.date() < datetime.added.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
        return date_added
```